# Salesforce Trigger skips the whole batch if there is error while updating atleast one record with Dataloader

Tags: triggers, salesforce, apex-code

I've written a trigger on Account object in Salesforce. When I upload records using Dataloader, this trigger executes on all records if there is no error. But, it misses the complete batch if there is an error while updating/insertiing at-least one record.

Can someone give some direction on this?

Please find below the two versions of the trigger(before and after):

VERSION-1

```
trigger accountScorerTrigger on Account (after insert, after update) {

if(Trigger.isUpdate || Trigger.isInsert) {               
    if(Utility.isFutureUpdate){
        List<Account> accList = new List<Account>();
        // Iterate through all records 
        for (Account newAccount:Trigger.new) {
            Account tempAcc = new Account(id = newAccount.id);
            tempAcc.Account_Score_History__c = 'TESTING RECORDS 3';
            accList.add(tempAcc);
        } 
        Utility.isFutureUpdate = false;
        if(accList.size()>0){ 
            //update accList; 
            Database.DMLOptions dml = new Database.DMLOptions();
            dml.optAllOrNone = false; // tried true also                
            database.update(accList,dml);
        }
    }        
}
}
```

VERSION-2

```
trigger accountScorerTrigger on Account (before insert, before update) {    
if(Trigger.isUpdate || Trigger.isInsert) {               
    //if(Utility.isFutureUpdate){
        // Iterate through all records 
        for (Account newAccount:Trigger.new) {
            newAccount.Account_Score_History__c = 'TESTING RECORDS 5';
        } 
        //Utility.isFutureUpdate = false;
    //}        
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Could use some more details but I assume you are performing a DML operation in the trigger. If you use the Database.insert(sobject[], allornone) or Database.update(subject[], allornone) methods you can specify all or none and handle the errors accordingly. Using the method directly from the Database object will return a SaveResult that you can then loop through and match back up with the trigger record to send the error back to the user or data loader.

Again need to see some sample code to give you a better answer.

Comment: Hi John, Thanks for your reply. Please find below two version of trigger (both skips the whole batch if there is any error in at-least one record)

Comment: Can you clarify if you are using both triggers or are these just two different ways that you have tried to solve the problem?